# HMAC SSL Certificate Question with OAuth

Tags: oauth, signature, hmac

I'm kinda new to this topic so please be gentle ;) I'm attempting to use a 3rd-party Health API called Dossia (http://dossia.org).

I setup a test account and have received my OAuth Consumer Key and Secret, in the config there's a line which says

> define('USER_SIG_METHOD','HMAC-SHA1');

My question is how do I make my server's "Signature Method" HMAC-SHA1?

This is just a non-ssl dev box with Fedora, I do have a production box with SSL on it, but I was hoping to get a sandbox post before moving it to production.

When I curl a post, I get a 404 error and the curl handle's info reads this:

```
 [ssl_verify_result] => -8179
```

So I'm assuming this is the issue, I have scoured their wiki, which is found [here](http://docs.dossia.org/index.php/Dossia_Application_Programming_Interface) however the only thing it says about the signature method is that they only support HMAC, do I need to include a certificate like the one on my prod box? Or am I going in completely the wrong direction?

Any advice would help me,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature Method was not the issue here, it was an issue with the record ID needed to be consistent in order to post to the right patient,